# How can I fix my Canon 600D's mode dial?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, camera-controls

My Canon 600D's mode dial can't be used to enter video mode. When I try to turn the dial to video, the onscreen display stops at sports. It never goes beyond that. And I have used the video mode many times!

[image: picture of stuck mode dial]

Comment: No SD card in it? Small card? And, totally unrelated, why is the hotshoe so dirty?

Comment: @xenoid Maybe not unrelated.  Grime under the mode dial could prevent it from working properly.

Comment: @xiota Locking the button on the next to last position? And that button is not as dirty as the hotshoe.

Comment: @xenoid You can't see what's *under* the dial.

Comment: @xiota grime under the dial would likely come with visible grime at the bottom. But mostly I would expect grime to block the button midway between the two positions.

Comment: @xenoid The problem isn't that the dial won't turn, but that the setting doesn't reflect the mode the dial is turned to.  (”the *onscreen* display stops at sports")

Comment: @xiota Ah, yes, bad contact it is then, possibly an aging dial worsened by [some dirt that crept into it](https://imgur.com/AeHttTu).

Comment: Dirt or corrosion?

Comment: This question has several issues, but I'm not sure why four people have voted to close as "off topic?" Sure, it needs more detail or clarity. Sure, we already have what seems like a kajillion duplicates of, "my camera is broken, what should I do?" But what part of the 'help center' says that questions about photographic equipment is off topic?

Comment: @inkista I'm not sure your edit makes sense. While the images previously included showed the mode dial not at "video", the text of OQ said something along the lines of "when I turn the mode dial to video, the display shows sport mode". It _sounds_ like the dial did turn to video, rather than being _physically_ stuck. Am I misreading the (original) problem?

Comment: @scottbb. Good note. I think you might be right. I'll re-edit. But Michael's comment about this being closed as a "video-not-photography" question also holds. This is a camera mode dial issue, not a video-mode question. I need to fix the image I broke, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your photo shows the mode selector knob at "Night Portrait" mode. Is that as far as it can physically move?

If your mode dial selector knob physically will not turn to the "Video" mode, your camera is broken and needs to be serviced. There can be no other explanation as to why the knob will not move to Video mode.

If the knob will move to "Video" but the camera stays stuck in "Sports", the prognosis is just as bad.

The T3i/600D body has a used value of about $200 so it may not be economically viable to repair it. It may be better to sell the body "as-is" and use the money to upgrade to a newer camera.